# Is there is no way to switch on/off meshes inside instances collections, what workflow can simulate this?

Tags: instances, collections

Kind of a theoretical question.

In *[Figma](https://www.figma.com/)* (an application for interface design) there is a concept of instances as it is in Blender. They work this way:

1. For example, you designing a collecting data form and should place a button "Confirm info" at the end.
2. This button should have 2 states: green (when all info is provided correctly) and grey (when there is a lack of info provided or some mistakes)
3. *Figma* allows you to assign 2 button designs (green & red) to one single button, so when you designing different screens you can simply choose the design of the button that suits the scenario in the outline panel. But it's still one button "Confirm info" – and that ability of one object to appear differently they call "instances"

I wonder if there is a way to work in Blender in the same fashion so one instance can appear differently in some details. For example, I have a whole house design I want to multiply (without creating additional data) in the scene but I want to have control over the door designs on this house (switch on the door I want/switch off the door I do not want) so that the houses look slightly differently outside. Is there a fast way to do that?

Comment: In Blender, there is also the concept of instances. The answer to your question depends on how you create the instances, I guess. For the button example, you could just assign a different material (red or green). If you create the instance of the door for the house with [Geometry Nodes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/instances/instance_on_points.html), you can select a random door from a collection or a specific door by index.

Comment: yes, I understand that there are instances in blender:) i guess i built my question incomprehensibly, so thank you for editing + I've edited a little myself. i am asking if there is a way to manipulate with appearance of different parts of instances (the house with doors that could be switched on/off is the example of what I am searching for)

I've got from your answer there is similar functionality in geonodes. I'll look into it, thanks!